# No me reemplaza los valores null

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Buenas...mi problema es que al momento de guardar en la base de datos se guarda como null es por eso que al llamarlo le doy una condicion de que si es null me pinte vacio pero no funciona...vi otra forma de hacerlo pero tampoco me funciono
algun consejo?

```js
<%
String ayuno= '';
COMANDO="SELECT AYUNO FROM PRUEBA.RECETA WHERE ID='22'" ;
  rset = stmt.executeQuery(COMANDO);
      if(rset.next()){
ayuno=rset.getString("ayuno");if(ayuno==null)ayuno="";
      }
%>
```

```html
<tr>
<td><label for="conf_nom_proc">Ayuno</label></td>
<td colspan="3"><input  type="text"  id="ayuno" name="ayuno" size="20" value="<%=ayuno%>" ></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hola Julio.... tu base de datos se llama prueba y tu tabla ayuno?

Comment: no,la columna se llama ayuno

Comment: En tu consulta select tienes esto: "SELECT AYUNO FROM PRUEBA.AYUNO WHERE ID='22'"; aquí estás diciendo que la base de datos se llama prueba y la tabla se llama ayuno

Comment: Perdón, error mio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba asi:

```
ayuno=rset.getString("ayuno");if(ayuno==null || ayuno.toUpperCase().equals("NULL"))ayuno="";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si resulto